# when development mode is switched off, language does not work

Tags: sugarcrm

I have installed Russian languag pack, I switched on "developer mode" and tested CRM. Language worked in all places. When I switched off developer mode, the subpanel titles were not translated into russian language(some are working and the other are not working). I cleared caches folder. However, issue still persist. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

For your information you have to add Russian Field names manually if missing. Because CRM works as following way

- CRM first check which language current user is using.
- If language is other than English then it will find the labels which are written in language files (for Russian: `\custom\include\language\rs_us.lang.php`). If label name will not found then it fetch from English language file
- So you have to check in language files whether the labels are in Russian language. If not add the labels in Russian language. you can also do label changes using Studio

Comment: Everything is working in developer mode on. However, when I switch off developer mode off, It does not working correctly.

Comment: Please try to run the CRM in Incognito / Private browser and let me know if same issue you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, I found answer. The problem was lang file located in module\language was deleted accedently. Therefore, it did not create lang cache file in cache folder. Consequently, it resulted in setting default(en_en) values in submenu panel titles.